# Loading an external font via inline CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, inline, font-face

Is it possible to load an external font via inline CSS?

Note: I'm *not* talking about using an external CSS file with a `@font-face` definition, but rather something like the following:

```
<h1 style="font-family:myfont;
    src:('http://example.com/font/myfont.tff')">test</h1>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is it possible loading an external font with inline css? NOT with an external CSS file [....].

Yes, you can base64 encode a font or fonts as shown in [this article](http://stephenscaff.com/articles/2013/09/font-face-and-base64-data-uri/) from Stephen Scaff and drop them into a `style` block in your page to avoid the external request.

It may also be possible to use this technique in the way you describe if the browser you're using supports it.

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'),
      url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAHowABMAAAAA+OAA) format('woff2');
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('PT Serif'), local('PTSerif-Regular'),
      url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAIQYABMAAAAA/MAA) format('woff2');
  }
</style>
```

Every modern browser [supports WOFF2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2), so you should probably use that *and only that* for the foreseeable future. Also, this technique will improve your page speed scores, but **will degrade performance** overall (even for first page loads), unless you're only base64-encoding critical page assets (e.g. glyphs of the font shown above the fold) and asynchronously load the rest.

Performance-wise your best bet right now is to use [Brotli compression](https://github.com/google/brotli) and pipe the webfont stylesheet down with [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/).

Comment: This is very interesting! My question is old back to 5 years ago and things are bit changed since then :) I am not able to verify it right now, but I am going to assume it as the "solution" so far.

Comment: this is still just a inline style tag not inline css like his example `<h1 style="...">`

Comment: Can the base64 encoded font(s) be dropped into a `<style>` tag *anywhere*, or just in the header?

Comment: Great option! I ended up using https://transfonter.org

Answer (score 12):

You cannot include a `@font-face` rule in a `style` attribute (which is “inline CSS” in the most narrow sense). By the HTML 4.01 specification, you cannot include such a rule inside the `body` element at all (“inline CSS” in a broader sense, which includes [`style` elements)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3). But in practice it is possible.

In practice, if you include a `style` element inside `body`, it will be processed by browsers just as if it were in the syntactically correct place, i.e. inside the `head` element. It even works “backwards”, effecting elements appearing before it.

You can even make this approach – which should be used only if you cannot change the `head` – formally correct as per HTML5 CR. It [allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) a `style` element at the start of any element with flow content as its content model. Current browsers ignore the `scoped` attribute.

**Update**: the following is not relevant any more, since the validator bug has been fixed.

However, there is a [bug](http://bugzilla.validator.nu/show_bug.cgi?id=968) in the W3C Markup Validator and in validator.nu: they disallow `style` at the start of `body`. To overcome this bug, and to make your document validate in addition to being valid, you can use an extra `div` element:

```
<body>
<div>
<style>
/* your @font-face and other CSS rules go here */
</style>
<!-- your document body proper goes here -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you link the relevant part of the HTML 4.01 specification which forbid this *(I'd like to know what other kind of inlined css is disallowed)*?

Comment: @user2284570, I added a clarification that refers to `style` elements, which can be called “inline CSS” in the broader sense that CSS code directly appears in an HTML document, instead of being in a separate CSS document that is just referred to in HTML. The HTML 4.01 rule that disallowed `style` inside `body` has no single location in the spec, since it follows from the *absence* of the `style` element from any content model except that of the `head` element.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, currently, I'm in a case`<style scoped></style>` and`<style></style>` is striped from the web sanitizer, but I can put anything inside a`style=""` attribute. Also, would it work if I use a`@import`inside a style attribute?

Comment: @user2284570, no, `@import` does not work inside a `style` attribute. The `style` attribute value can only consist of declarations (*name*: *value*), which will be applied to the current element.

Comment: This does not work for me - errors at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

No, not that I know of. You will need to declare this kinds of things on a `<style>` block or an external CSS file.

Though if you want something like this, it's very probable you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `Though if you want something like this, it's very probable you're doing it wrong.`: What about embedding a font on a single mediawiki page?

Comment: @user2284570 MediaWiki allows you to define a custom CSS file IIRC. I haven't used it in a very long time.

Comment: Yes, but they allow it only for the whole site. If you have a single page which require a 6Mb font, then it will be loaded in all the page of the site.

Comment: @user2284570 In that case you are most definitely doing *something* wrong.

Comment: [Maybe not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs) :-)

Comment: 6mb font O.o are you loading the entire google font lib?

Comment: @PatsyIssa : No, but elaborate glyphs require a lot of data *(There are several different word maps on the page)*

Answer (score -6):

If you use @font-face, you should be able to do something like this:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RalewayThin';
src: url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg#RalewayThin') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Make sure to include the fonts - the above example has placed all of the fonts in a relative-path directory to the css file.

**HTML**

```
<h1 style="font-family:RalewayThin,Helvetica, sans-serif;">
```

You should be able to find free web-based @font-face fonts [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface).

Comment: It's kinda the point to do the declaration inside of the `style=` attribute ;)