# Is there an inline equivalent to @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm faced with a problem, I can't edit the css or javascript of a webpage. Only it's body.
So, I need to use a font that all systems don't support.
So is there any way I can use @font-face inline?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749225/loading-external-font-in-html-page-with-inline-css).

Comment: @WChargin: Oh, I didn't find that question. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new css on it's body part?

```
<body>
   <style>
      @font-face ...
   </style>

   ...
</body>
```

or using external stylesheet with @font-face inside it.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='webfont.css' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily "overwrite" css by adding a code like the following in your balise head:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'new-font';
    ...
  }

  p {
    font-family:'new-font';
  }
</style>
```