# How to load CSS asynchronously without using JavaScript?

Tags: css, performance

Suppose if I have a website http://somethingsomething.com

And I have 3 css file

- common.css
- homepage.css
- inner-pages.css

`homepage.css` is required for homepage and `common.css` is for whole site but `inner-pages.css` is for other pages only and it's big file. Is it possible to load `inner-pages.css` after homepage data download. In the same way like we use `async` attribute for `script` tag. As far as I know  `async` attribute is only for JS not CSS

my one friend suggested to use requirejs for this http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css but I don't want to use javascript to load css and even I would think upon JS way i would not use require.js just for this. So if it is not possible with CSS only. what would be the simple JS way to do this?

Comment: This seems negligible, how big are the files? What kind of performance gain will you get? I think it would be wiser to just minify everything together. Once a user navigates past the homepage the benefits would disappear. As far as I know there is no way to load CSS files async w/o JS.

Comment: @DavidNguyen _ Yes what you said I already know. just wanted to check if someone has different opinion or trick.

Comment: As David Nguyen says, if you minify and put all the css in one file, the first load will be bad, but the next loads will be in cache, so it will be fast. But anyway, I'm curious if its possible without javascript...

Comment: Actually I you should be able to load async using an iframe...answer below

Comment: could [this](https://gist.github.com/omo/9986103) be of interest to the discussion?

Answer (score 9):

Async CSS with media="bogus" and a `<link>` at the foot
Say we've got our HTML structured like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- unimportant nonsense -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="bogus">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- other unimportant nonsense, such as content -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</body>
```

More at http://codepen.io/Tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can place an iframe in your page pointing to some dummy page that serves the CSS, that should serve the CSS file async.

`<iframe src="loadcss.html"></iframe>`

Do note it seems pretty trivial, this causes a minimum of 2 css file transfers per page and 3 css file transfers per child page (if it isn't cached). If you were to minify the css you would only have 1 transfer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/css.css',
    type:'get',
    success:function(css){
        $('html').append('<style>'+css+'</style>');
    }
});
```

or

```
function getCss(url){
    $('<link>',{rel:'stylesheet',type:'text/css','href':url}).appendTo('head');
}

getCss('/css.css');
```

---

ok sorry I didn't see you don't want to use javascript

how about using css @import:

```
<style>
@import url('/style1.css');
@import url('/style2.css');
</style>
```

Comment: Javascript would be the last resort.

Comment: @import is even worse than <link>: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199364/import-vs-link

Answer (score 0):

Include your CSS in the `<body>` instead of `<head>` ... "it seems this trick causes Chrome & Firefox to start the body earlier, and they simply don't block for body stylesheets." and add a condition for IE:

**head**

```
<head>
  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <!-- blocking, but what else can ya do? -->
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**body**

```
<body>
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" lazyload>
  <!-- <![endif]-->
</body>
```

by [Taylor Hunt](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript) @codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

As suggested Require is not necessary for loading CSS assets. If you want to get your larger payloads asynchronously without relying on JavaScript you should be looking at leveraging HTTP/2 Server Push to deliver your non-critical style assets. And here's a [performance technique you may find useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43465666/712334) for delivering critical CSS payloads for browsers which works well even today.

Finally, if you are optimizing your pages for performance and don't want to pull in heavy or complicated tools like Require I've an alternative [minimal asset loader](https://habd.as/code/fetch-inject/) you may use if you like.