# Jboss 7 serving static resources asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, jboss7.x, nio

Since Jboss supports Servlet 3.0, servlets can serve in an asynch manner. However, how do i configure jboss or application so that static resources like javascript files, css files and images can be served in an asynchronous manner?

Following link doesn't help either
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/aio.html

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and from everything that I have read, *Asynchronous support in Servlet 3* does **NOT** serve web resources.  It is used for asynchronously handling `HttpServlet` `Requests` and `Responses` so that your AJAX doesn't get hung up waiting for database connection pooling and the like.

---

**How to asynchronously serve JavaScript and CSS**

- It is import to place all of your `<script>` tags/calls at the **end** of the `<body>`, right before the `</body>`. This ensure that your HTML gets loaded before any fetching or running of the scripts happen.
- The simplest way to serve JavaScript asynchronously is to use HTML5 and add the 'async' attribute.  *NOTE: this may only be used for linking JavaScript code with the `src` attribute, it will not work for JavaScript in the `<script>` tag.*

  ```
  <script async src="../js/your-javascript-code.js"></script>
  ```
- If you can not use HTML5 or the `async` attribute is not supported, you can do the following taken from [Thinking Async](http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/):

  ```
  (function(d, t) {
      var g = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      g.src = '//third-party.com/resource.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
  }(document, 'script'));
  ```
- [How to asynchronously load CSS using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186638/how-to-asynchronously-load-css-using-jquery)
- [Dynamically loading css file using javascript with callback without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537622/dynamically-loading-css-file-using-javascript-with-callback-without-jquery)
- [How to load CSS asynchronously without using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819074/how-to-load-css-asynchronously-without-using-javascript)

---

In case you are interested, here is working [example](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.3.x-develop/servlet-async) of how to use the Servlet 3 asynchronous feature, demonstrating it's intended use, running on JBoss.