# How to load a font file in the html <head> tag

Tags: fonts, tags, load, head

I want to load the following font file in the html  of the [website](http://me.sage.com) due to delayed rendering of this file in the style.css of about 3.6s loading time.

http://me.sage.com/wp-content/themes/sage_theme/fonts/foco-webfont-webfont.woff

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading external font in html page with inline css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749225/loading-external-font-in-html-page-with-inline-css)

Comment: and remember: if you load it in the head, that's 3.6s that people won't see anything, and if their connection is choppy, much longer. That's absolutely not better than at least seeing site content, just not styled with what you might feel is the perfect font, but really makes no difference to the user in terms of "being able to read what's on the page"