# custom font will not display not matter what i do

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

i want to add a custom font to my html page, but it does not work, i tried everything possible, checked other questions, trying to solve it their way, but nothing.

the font is in the same folder as my html file(the css is in the html file)

In html css i wrote:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: regular;
    src: url("8bitoperator_jve.ttf");
    //src: local("8bitoperator_jve.ttf"); i tried this too
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: regular;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find a specific font in local, but a font file in url. I mean, the local font doesn't need any path or file extension whereas a font file need it. If you want to target a local files first you can try like that:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: regular;
    src: local("8bitoperator_jve"),url("8bitoperator_jve.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

Also you can try loading the font-face from an external CSS file.

Comment: Have you tried without local ?  src: url("8bitoperator_jve.ttf");

Comment: yes, is there a reason why microsoft edge is the only one that's working?

Comment: I kwow that maybe it could be impossible to charge font file directly from html document. Perhaps you could try loading the font face inside an external CSS file ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749225/loading-external-font-in-html-page-with-inline-css

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) specifies the resource containing the font data. This can be:

- `url`: a **URL** to a remote font file location;
- `local`: the **name** of a font on the user's computer.

In your case, you are passing a URL to `local`. Instead, you should use `url`:

```
@font-face {
    src: url('8bitoperator_jve.ttf');
}
```

If you want, you can also use both. But remember to give precedence to `local`, *i.e.*:

```
@font-face {
    src: local('Name of your font here'), url('8bitoperator_jve.ttf');
}
```

Comment: i tried both url and local, last thing i tried was local and forgot to change back to url, but still nothing, now it works with micosoft edge tho, but nothing on IE or chrome