# How to change @Font-Face property for load new font via [ngStyle] in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to change the font whenever user choose a new one . So I want to load only that font which is selected by user . So how this is possible in angular 2 ?

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749225/loading-an-external-font-via-inline-css to me

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please read my carefully again its not dup

Comment: How does reading carefully change anything? Just because you added Angular and `ngStyle`? It's till boils down to a browser and JavaScript ;-)

Comment: but @GünterZöchbauer the link you asked is not taking me to the solution

Comment: It would be more helpful if you'd add information to your question **how** it is not leading you to a solution. `[ngStyle]` is adding inline styles. The linked answer explains how to add `@Font-Face` using inline styles. If that is not what you want, you will probably need to make a feature request on the different browsers to make this easier.